# How to make a navigation system between views with java

Tags: java, user-interface, architecture, navigation, command-line-interface

I have been stuck with an issue for quite a while.

I am making a simple educational Java software and i didn't find any example of navigation systeme to switch between pages.
What i mean is that i am making a "core" exposing an API and differents user interfaces including command line interface(cli), graphical user interface(gui), web interface and probably an android app.
My issue is about the CLI but should probably be applied to the GUI too: how would you switch from a page to another?

I have tried to make it such as an enum implementing an interface including a function that instantiate the view. This way a view returns the specific enum of the view to display. The enum is then executed to make the view. But is really seems inefficient and complicated even tho it is scalable.

Here is a simple representation of what i am aiming at.

```
Launcher
-> System.out.println("welcome");
-> go to Authenticate

Authenticate
-> System.out.println("1: sign in, 2: login")
-> if(input == 1) go to SignIn
-> else go to LogIn

SignIn
-> System.out.println("enter username and password")
-> username = input
-> password = input
-> new User(username, password)
-> go to Authenticate

LogIn
-> print("enter username")
-> go to Etc...
```

Shouldn't the navigation be centralized to avoid memory loss if a view is called by another? Shouldn't a "menu" centralize all the view calls to make the code readable?

Might be a dumb question but i haven't found an answer and i would really like one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In larger systems there is usually a controller layer which is generally responsible for routing a user from one view to another.  This is the C in [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  The implementation of this depends on the framework you use, many frameworks specify a particular methodology for routing between views.  Others are more adhoc, and allow the view layer to control that navigation.

You are basically building this controller layer in your application in your enum.

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for your answer. I am indeed following the MVC model but shouldn’t be the navigation system linked to the View part as the Controller is only an API that will be plugged to different interfaces? Also, you are referring to a Framework: is that what swing and javaFx are? Even tho Java has been around for quite a while hasn’t been a command line “framework” or guideline that has been developed to which I could refer to? Thank you for your time!

Comment: I have never seen a framework for CLI,  such a thing *could* exist, but I've never seen one in the wild.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904115/mvc-on-the-command-line talks about some of the issues you are discussing.  You *could* decouple the view name from the strings that are output onto the CLI, that is certainly possible, it would be complicated, but having a CLI output "renderer" would accomplish what you are attempting (abstracting the CLI from the controller).  This is likely massive overkill and would only be an academic exercise.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. So how would you (personnaly) handle the CLI display? Through static methodes called from one view to another? A unique class containing all the interface content? This is an exercice i am doing to demonstrate my abilities so i am trying to do something as clean as possible or at least as professional (standard) as i can. Does that also mean that an API doesn't fit in a MVC model?